# Changing expanding appostrophed words

Tags: r, nlp

I have a number of strings such as "*I'm not going*", "*The beer's great*", etc.

Is there a way I can expand them, i.e. "*I am not going*", "*The beer is great*".

Comment: Keep in mind that "'s" can mean "is" or "has" or even "us".

Comment: @Roland. I was wondering whether there is anything that can do this. R fascinates me with the amount of packages it comes with.

Comment: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/qdap/docs/contractions ; this looks like it will *not* handle something like "beer's".

Comment: If you want proper handling of contractions, the easiest way to use a language model. I'm not aware of any package that does exactly what you want, but [openNLP](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openNLP/index.html) can handle language models and so could be used to implement what you need quite easily.